# oauth authentication development for struts application

Tags: java, jquery, oauth, struts2, joauth

I want to develop oauth for one of "localhost" application. can u guide how to develop with any useful links. Initially i am looking for authentification only.

Do we need to use separate APIs for facebook, gmail and twitter?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need separate library for using Oauth for your application, there is a very handy and light weight API [scribe-java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) which provides Oauth implementation for almost all major provider namely Google,Facebook,Yahoo,MSN and others.

Have a look at there [getting-started](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) guide which is quite easy and clear